# SSO Authentication in two projects and same user ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to authenticate in my application (www.domain1.com) using Identity and I want to be redirected to another app (www.domain2.com/Account/Login) and after logging returning to the first app (domain1.com)
thank you

Comment: check this article : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic

Comment: @PowerMouse Thanks but I need ASP.NET MVC instead of Web Forms, Thanks